# How to find child node with equalTo query in Firebase with Swift?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase hierarchy.

<kbd>[image: 1]</kbd>

How can I write a query which finds the child where the value is `1` AND I don't know that it is under the node `V9T3cEgEGPRmIkMQb32hxa5gG7L2`? In this case, I want to find and print out `-KeYbk3K1xXlyzOGVVPx` (this uid key is generated by Firebase). The main node is `eventUser`.

Comment: You can only get an eventOrganized with values of 1 if you specify the specific eventUser node. Or, you can get all eventUsers which have an eventOrganized with a value of one. What you want is impossible. If you want all eventOrganizeds with a value of 1 over your entire database you'll have to manually loop through it in your code.

Comment: By the way, this is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609735/firebase-queryequal-doesnt-work

Comment: (1) not quite the same question, because here I'm trying to raise a generic question about Firebase quering and the prevous one was too specific and confusing with the codes (2) you mentioned "you can get all eventUsers which have an eventOrganized with a value of one" how does it look like? with the answer of the prevoius thread I didn't get those records

Comment: I ment to say you can get all eventUsers which have a specific eventOrganized with a value of one. But I already gave you that query and you said it didn't work (even though it should). I think you'd be better of finding a way to restructure your database.

Comment: This looks similar to what I described in my answer on categorization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value. As Pieter says, that would require a different data model to do efficiently.

Comment: I was thinking about it as well, but what is your idea regarding restructuring? V9T3cEgEGPRmIkMQb32hxa5gG7L2 is the userid given by FB and -KeYbk3K1xXlyzOGVVPx is the eventid given by FB. With current stucture I want to store the Event ids under the User id, where the User attended with Status = 1

Answer (score 0):

Pass the node value in `nodeVal`

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/eventUser/' + nodeVal).once('value').then(function(q) {
   var eventItem = q.val().eventitem;
   console.log(eventitem);  
});
```

Comment: This is a Swift question, why would you answer in JavaScript?